# What documents do I need to be able to sign a rental contract Brussels, Belgium?

Tags: rental, belgium, documentation

I have Italian citizenship, and would like to know what documents do I need in order to be able to sign a rental contract in Brussels.

Comment: I don't know how things are in Brussels but in Antwerpen, as you're a member of UE, you just need your passport number. But it depends with kind rental contract you'll do. Directly with the owner, real state agency...and you'll need to pay at least 2 months rental in advance.

Answer (score 2):

After doing some research on the Belgium's official work site, I found an article talking about foreigner who want to work in Belgium.

You need to take with you:

-The visa for your stay in Belgium.

-The work permission document from Belgium (which is called "permis de travail").

-Your driving license.

http://www.emploi.belgique.be/defaultTab.aspx?id=4888

Comment: Do you have a source/reference for this?

Comment: Yes I mentionned the web site where I found this answer. This is http://www.emploi.belgique.be/defaultTab.aspx?id=4888.

Comment: -1 Being Italian, OP doesn't need a visa or a working permission. That article is for non-EU/EEA citizens, as the "Présentation" part says.

Answer (score 2):

I'm an EU national as well, and I only needed my national ID card for the landlord to verify my identity. We used [this model contract](http://www.immoweb.be/Mx_pdf/5058_2A8CA5B1-A9CA-BBC9-D2C8158452A3E14E_fr.pdf), which as you can see, only requires your name and address.

I also had to sign forms (in quadruplicate!) for transitioning the utility contracts, which asked for my residence registration number. I didn't have one at the time (the process can take a while), but the utility's call center assured me I didn't need to fill that in, and I didn't receive any complaints from them after submitting the documents.